# Selenoid: recording video of a running session

Tags: selenium, testing, video, vnc, selenoid

I'm using [Selenoid](http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) live browser screen [functionality](http://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_live_browser_screen) to debug my tests. What is the recommended way to capture browser screen video?

Answer (score 3):

**UPD2:** released in Selenoid [1.4.0](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/releases/tag/1.4.0).

---

**UPD1:** currently [working](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/issues/255) on native video recording feature in Selenoid. Should be available starting from release 1.4.0.

---

Selenoid supports showing video via VNC. What you need to do is just grab it from respective port. Here is one possible way to record video from VNC.

**Requirements:**

1. Selenoid must be running in as a binary (not as Docker container) otherwise the mapped ports are `null`.
2. Docker APIs should be exposed to the outside world. (http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html)

**How to do that.** One possible solution is to use [vnc2flv](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/) script.

1. Download the script: `$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/1e/8e/40c71faa24e19dab555eeb25d6c07efbc503e98b0344f0b4c3131f59947f/vnc2flv-20100207.tar.gz\#md5\=8492e46496e187b49fe5569b5639804e`
2. Unpack the archive: `$ tar zxf vnc2flv-20100207.tar.gz`
3. Install the script: `$ python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local`
4. Record the video: get Docker container ID via Selenoid `/status` and then find with Docker commands which port is mapped to the container port `5900` (the VNC port). Then type: `flvrec.py -P <filename_for_password_file> -o <output_video_filename> <hub_host> <the_vnc_port>`, e.g. `flvrec.py -P password.txt -o /tmp/selenoid_videos/gimme_love.flv 172.31.11.135 32774`.
5. Saved video file can be found in `/tmp/selenoid_videos/gimme_love.flv`.